# Semi supervised learning for Regression task with tabular data?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science, tabular, non-linear-regression

- Semi-supervised learning for Regression task with tabular data? I have like 20K labelled data and 200K unlabeled data.
- Model gets better and better with semi-supervised learning for eg. self-learning and on top of it if you have just 20K and making predictions on 200K you assume variance and distribution of features remain same which is not always true so you make a prediction with a sizeable error even your model was 90 Mean R2 on K Fold CV. Hope that explains why I am searching for a semi-supervised approach for regression!

Comment: why do u say it semi supervised. You have 20K records to train your model and remaining you should execute for prediction

Comment: @SwaritAgarwal model gets better and better with semi-supervised learning for eg. self-learning and on top of it if you have just 20K and making predictions on 200K you assume variance and distribution of features remain same which is not always true so you make a prediction with a sizeable error even your model was 90 Mean R2 on K Fold CV. Hope that explains why I am searching for a semi-supervised approach for regression!

Comment: That make sense. but what accuracy and R2 for your 20K records. I believe more data does improve your model. Have a try to ridge regression. Hope that resolve your concern

Comment: Well my K Fold R2 is pretty high on 20K data and I am trying all non-linear models like XGBoost, Neural Nets, etc. Ridge is a linear model and won't help

Comment: and what would the question be? Could you please update the question to add all the information you gave in the comments and ask a question that make sense. Semi supervised learning classification with manifold regularization could be of help by recoding the simple algorithm of regression (kmean for regression for example) on top of LapSVM.

Answer (score 0):

A key assumption for most semi-supervised learning (SSL) is that nearby points (e.g. between an unlabelled and labelled point) are likely to share the same label. It seems you're expecting the variance and distribution of your unlabelled set to be different to your labelled set which *may* violate the above assumption.

If you still wish to go ahead with SSL then there are no conventional techniques for regression methods. But...

The literature on less conventional methods has been reviewed: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325798856_Semi-supervised_regression_A_recent_review

And...

You could always convert to a classification approach (helps if the labels are relatively uniformly distributed). For instance, just choose the median prediction value in your labelled set, then everything less than that is 0 and everything greater is 1. You can then apply a conventional classification SSL technique, such as label propagation. Then, you get the predicted probabilities on a test set (e.g. use `predict_proba()`) and scale these back to your regression range. For example, if the minimum value in your labelled set was 0 and the max was 10, then just multiply the predicted probabilities by 10.

Hope the above at least provides food for thought.